# Add to cart in Shopify with API

Tags: php, react-native, shopify, shopify-app

I just started using Shopify and it's APIs but I'm unable to complete my checkout process.
I'm using PHP as a backend and creating a react-native app. how can I achieve this?
I checked the Shopify-PHP-SDK, REST Admin API but didn't find anything helpful.

This is the first app that I've built using the Shopify API, so I'd appreciate any guidance that I can get. I looked into signing up with a partner application and using the OAuth authentication, but that seems like overkill for what I need to do since I don't want to use the Shopify storefront and I don't plan on offering my app in the Shopify App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You must have missed this obvious choice.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to avoid storefront.
but now i have to use this because no option left for me.

Comment: How can i get the cart data using the storefront API?

Comment: It is labeled a checkout, not a cart. You add items to a checkout. Not a cart. Switch the word cart for checkout and you're good to go.

Comment: sorry "checkout",(because in bigcommerce it is called cart) i am unable to find any API call to get the checkout data in Storefront API

Comment: thanks for your help @David, i found it here https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/checkoutattributesupdatev2

Comment: will u please help me how to update checkout line items? how to add line items to existing checkout? 
i'm also unable to get the discounts that i applied using the storefront api.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Storefront API, you can also use [Ajax API](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api). Unlike Storefront API, it doesn't require authentication.